# magento - delete extension?

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I bought a magento extension and copied the files into the magento directory.  Everything worked great.  Then I wanted to re-install it.  So I deleted all relevant files in app/code/local and i deleted the relevant database tables.

When I re-copied the extension files back into the magento directory and tried to test the extension out, i get this error:

`SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mydb.swam_list' doesn't exist`

I looked in the database and it seems magento did not re-create the database tables for the extension.

How do I re-install this extension?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look in the table `core_resource` for an entry matching the module's name. Delete that and it will install from scratch on the next page request, possibly not until after a cache flush.

Comment: more specifically, the entry in the table will be the same name as the subfolder under `sql` in the install files.  Something like `swam_setup` is likely.

Comment: another of Magento's somewhat obscure but mostly useful conventions! :)

Comment: I deleted every file, also the entry on core_resource, flushed every cache, but the entry on the backend is still there. Any idea?

Comment: @KlevisMiho I am not aware of anything else that needs to be cleared. Perhaps you missed a file or are looking at the wrong extension?

Comment: I needed to delete a record from the table eav_attribute too.